# Queueable Apex Running For Long duration

Tags: apex, code, asyncapexjob, queueable

I am triggering a queueable apex but the class running for very long duration is very small class and perform apex sharing.

[image: Duration of queueable]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

956m milliseconds is over ten days. There's no way the transaction could have run this long, both because there's a hard limit of ten minutes, and the fact that this log was generated today. In other words, you just ran into a rare bug where the duration is calculated incorrectly. You'll need to read the logs to determine the actual runtime. Your code is likely running just fine.